# Why does assigning a variable to _ doesn't throw declared but not used error in go?

Tags: go

I have declared a variable 'x' but haven't *used* it.

```golang
package main

func main() {
 var x int = 10
 _ = x
}
```

In the above program I am assigning the value of `x` to `_` (blank identifier).

A blank identifier is a write-only variable and cannot be used, as such it is as good as saying that `x` is not used here.

1. But why doesn't it throw error? Is not `x` waste of memory?
2. Should not the compiler, treat `x` as declared but not used?
3. Is it a bug or is it intentional?
4. If it is intentional, what is the reason behind this?
5. Does go compiler automatically add any instruction to free `x` memory in the above program?
6. If a lot of such variables are created and assigned to `_` would it have any performance impact?

Comment: Because that is how the language is [specified](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignments): _"The blank identifier provides a way to ignore right-hand side values in an assignment:"_. What the compiler actually does is entirely an implementation detail.

Comment: @JimB I want to know that implementation detail.

Comment: Well, the default Go compiler does not use LLVM, so there is no LLVM instruction to look at. Look at the compiled machine code to see what it does with your particular compiler implementation and version.

Comment: The standard Go compiler uses [SSA](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_single_assignment_form) optimizations, meaning it's easy to find and remove instructions for ineffectual assignments (such as assignments to `_`). Whether or not it will actually do this in any particular case, would require an expert to weigh in, or testing it yourself (most of us don't study compilers in depth).

Answer (score 3):

> But why doesn't it throw error?

Because the language spec says it shouldn't.

> Is not x waste of memory?

This is an implementation detail, not related to the language spec. One can reasonably assume it's *not* going to use memory, since there's no variable there, but there are many Go implementations, and each can make its own decision in this regard.

> Should not the compiler, treat x as declared but not used?

No.

> Is it a bug or is it intentional?

It's intentional.

> If it is intentional, what is the reason behind this?

Aside from asking the language author(s), speculation is the only possibility, which is off-topic on StackOverflow.

> Does go compiler automatically add any instruction to free x memory in the above program?

Again, this is an implementation detail, not defined by the spec, and subject to change.

> If a lot of such variables are created and assigned to _ would it have any performance impact?

Probably not. But once again, this is an implementation detail, and could vary between implementations.

Comment: So, are the implementation details considered off-topic in SO? Why cannot the answer include some explanation on the implementation details?

Comment: They are not off-topic, no. But because there are many implementations, you must specify which one you're interested in. It would be impractical at best, and likely impossible, to list all implementations and how they handle this, even if that could be known.

Answer (score 2):

1- It is a declared local variable, and it is used. Why would it be an error? The compiler may choose to optimize it by eliminating it.

2- `x` is declared, and used. It's value is read, and thrown away

3/4- There is no point in using `_` assignment like this. There are other uses of it, for instance, in a `range` statement

5- Above, `x` did not escape to heap, so it is allocated on stack. There is no  need to free it.

Comment: 2. Why to *read* and throw it away. If you are reading something, it should be used. What is the point of reading it without *using* it?

Comment: For instance: `for _,x:=range slice {...}`

Comment: My question, is why at all memory should be allocated to variable `x` in the first place in the context of the above program

Comment: You don't know it is allocated. The compiler may ignore it. The point is, as written it is a valid go program.

Comment: It's probably not allocated at all, and the entire thing is elided during SSA analysis.

Comment: In case, it is not allocated, why not throw an error? The same code, with the `_ =x` line commented out throws the error, why not this?

Comment: Because without `_=x` ,  `x` is declared but never used. That is how `_` assignment works.

Comment: @BurakSerdar I say, both are same, IMO in the context of the above program.

Comment: No they are not. Read the language spec.

Comment: @JavaTechnical: The language specifies that this is valid Go. Asking why the language designers decided to design it this way is off topic for SO, and not a very useful question in general https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/323382/32880

Comment: @JimB hmm, could be. but may be from performance point of view, I would like to know if declaring a lot of variables as such and assigning them to `_` would have any impact? May be I can add this to the question to make it on-topic?

Comment: @JavaTechnical: the only way to absolutely measure impact is to test actually measure it. In this simple example, you can dump the machine code and see the 2 lines in question are not compiled at all.